# Issue with choice action when running transform map

Tags: servicenow

I'm trying to insert records to a table by using transform maps. I have this field in the target table, which is a choice type, and I have set the choice action in the source table's field to reject if there's no matching value found. But, when I tried inserting the record using the transform map with the correct value, which exists in the choice list of the target field, it still got rejected and hence not inserting the records.

I have tried searching for possible reasons as to why it still got rejected even with correct value in the source field. Here's the sample link that I have found: https://hi.service-now.com/kb_view.do?sysparm_article=KB0677334

It says that if there are more than 40 characters for the choice list value it will be truncated and might not match those choice. But the choices in the target field has only 20 characters or less.

I have first tried running the transform map in the lower environments before proceeding to production. In the lower environment it works fine and the records got inserted. But, when I tried it in production it got rejected.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between choice and choice list. Within the choice list the values are comma separated sys_ids. I could imagine that you have multiple values for import and then the max character are reached or the values do not match, etc. 
You could use this approach:
Instead of a direct assignment, source to target field, use the script to target. Then you gain the full script power ;)

[image]

Maybe here you could add some logic like switch case or whatever, I guess you get the point.